# how to execute a array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i am new with jQuery and i want to make an array to be executed.So i make an array of same class of divs.those are like that

```
<div class="block"><img src="/home/ranjit/Desktop/Test/sunrise1.jpg" alt="sunset" /></div>
<div class="block"><img src="/home/ranjit/Desktop/Test/sunset-sailing.jpg" alt="sunset1" /></div>
```

look that each of div having different data in an array and i make the array like this

```
var matches = [];
jQuery(".block").each(function() {
    matches.push(this);
});
```

now i want to run the function

```
function slider() {
    for (var i= 0; i < len; i++){
      console.log(matches[i]);
      jQuery(matches[i]).show("slow");
      jQuery(matches[i]).animate({left:'+=730'}, 3000, function(){
        jQuery(this).animate({left:'-=730'},3000);
      });
    }
  }
```

when i call the the slider function it executed the last of the div only. why i dont know, but i think it should logically executed the first div then the second div. plz help me why is this not executed like that .

Comment: no sense pushing them into an array if you're just going to loop over them immediately. Actually.. `$('.block')` already behaves like an array, so what you're doing is completely redundant. Just assign it to a variable if you really need to.

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop has `i < len` but you didn't define `len` anywhere.

You probably want `i < matches.length`

As an alternative to the for loop, use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Another potential issue is that you need to queue the animation effects. from [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> queue: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string.

Comment: yes, i use len as len = matches.length; but the jQuery.each function didnot work like that i want. i want that the first div is executed first when the for loop condition meet true, then the second one.

Comment: You may need to queue the animations. See my edits to the answer above.